# How to use NetworkRechabilityManager of Alamofire in the app?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have an iOS app implemented in Swift. I am using Alamofire and hence I have a file named as 'NetworkRechabilityManager.swift'. I have gone through many online tutorials and got it's working.

I have a page in my app whose data is fetched from an API. While checking response's status code in the 'HomePageViewController' file I planned to apply network reachability for 'response == nil'.

```
if response == nil {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: ("www.xyz.com/api/v1/home_page")!)
    let tempRequest1 = Requests(request: request,requestID: home_page_key)
    HelperClass.requestDict.updateValue(tempRequest1!, forKey: home_page_key)
    HelperClass.listner()
    HelperClass.manager?.startListening()
}
```

In my HelperClass I have:

```
static var requestDict: [String: Requests] = [String: Requests]()
{
    didSet
    {
        if(requestDict.count <= 0 && shouldStopListening()) 
        {
            HelperClass.manager?.stopListening()
        }
        else
        {
            HelperClass.manager?.startListening()
        }
        HelperClass.saveRequests()
    }
}

static func listner()
{
    if(shouldStopListening())
    {
        return
    }
    HelperClass.manager?.listener = { status in
        if(HelperClass.manager?.isReachable ?? false)
        {
            if(shouldStopListening())
            {
                return
            }
            execRequests()
            }
        }
}
```

And In the 'HomePageViewController' file for response is 200,

```
if response == 200 { // performing required actions and 
    HelperClass.requestDict.removeValue(forKey: home_page_key)
}
```

It seems not working, Can anyone give an example of implementing Alamofire with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like that

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
class ConnectivityManager {
    class var isConnectedToInternet:Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
    }
}
```

And use it like that

```
 if !ConnectivityManager.isConnectedToInternet {
            print("not connected")
            return
     }
      // continue your task
```

Comment: Thank for quick response but this is what to check internet connection but what I want is to enter my request URl in a dictionary and hit that URl automatically as device get Internet connection. Hence in my HelperClass I have requestDict structure for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Reachability" third party class which provides callbacks during the internet change and internet fluctuations.

here: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift